# Testing Go project with gomodules in Gitlab CI fails with "package is not in GOROOT"

Tags: gitlab, go-modules

I'm trying to build and test a Go project on Gitlab CI using the following .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: golang:latest

stages:
  - prepare
  - test
  - build
  - package

format:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - make gofmt    

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make test

test race condition:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make race

coverage-html:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make cov

build win binary:
  stage: build
  script:    
    - make win

build linux binary:
  stage: build
  script:    
    - make linux
    
build mac binary:
  stage: build
  script:    
    - make mac
```

and here is the Makefile used in the pipeline:

```
# Go parameters
GOCMD=go
GOBUILD=$(GOCMD) build
GOCLEAN=$(GOCMD) clean
GOTOOL=$(GOCMD) tool
GOTEST=$(GOCMD) test
GOTESTRACE=$(GOTEST) -race
GOGET=$(GOCMD) get
GOFMT=$(GOCMD)fmt

BINARY_NAME=app
BINARY_DARWIN=$(BINARY_NAME)_darwin
BINARY_LINUX=$(BINARY_NAME)_linux
BINARY_WIN=$(BINARY_NAME)_win
    
all: build linux win

build: ## Download dependecies and Build the default binary      
        $(GOBUILD) -o $(BINARY_NAME) -v $(CURDIR)/cmd/app

linux: ## Build linux binary
        CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) cmd/app -o $(BINARY_LINUX) -v $(CURDIR)/cmd/app

win: ## Build windows binary
        CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o $(BINARY_WIN).exe -v  $(CURDIR)/cmd/app

mac: ## Build macOs binary
        CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o $(BINARY_DARWIN) -v    $(CURDIR)/cmd/app

test: ## Run tests for the project
        $(GOTEST) -count=1 -coverprofile=cover.out -short -cover -failfast ./... -v

race: ## Run tests for the project (while detecting race conditions)
        $(GOTESTRACE) -coverprofile=cover.out -short -cover -failfast ./...

cov: test ## Run tests with HTML for the project
        $(GOTOOL) cover -html=cover.out

gofmt: ## gofmt code formating
    @echo Running go formating with the following command:
    $(GOFMT) -e -s -w .
```

I'm using `gomodule` to manage dependencies. What I'm struggling to understand is that if I run jobs in `build` stage first, the pipeline is able to download dependencies and build the binaries successfuly. But when jobs in the `test` stage are run, they all fail with the following error:

```
main.go:3:8: package app/command is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/app/command)
make: *** [Makefile:31: test] Error 1
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Is there a different setting for testing `gomodule` based projects on Gitlab CI that I need to configure?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? What was the reason?

Comment: What is the module path declared in your `go.mod` file? (Is it `app`?) At first glance this looks like your `main.go` is importing `app/command` via the wrong path, but there isn't really enough detail here to say for sure.